# django pass model fields to BetterForm

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use BetterForms to group the fields and add a legend to each group.

For example i have this model:

**models.py**

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="2", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="2", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="3")
    citizenship = models.ManyToManyField(Citizenship, help_text="4")
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocForm(BetterForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="3")

    class Meta:
        model = Doc
        fieldsets = [
            ('main',
             {'fields': ['name', 'citizenship'],
              'legend': 'I. PERSONAL DATA'}),

            ('main1',
             {'fields': ['series', 'number'],
              'legend': 'II. PROFESSIONAL IDENTIFICATION'})]
```

I have many more fields than i've written here. Is there a possibility to pass the model fields as in ModelForm instead of writing each field in the form again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked in the end for me:

```
class DocForm(BetterModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Anexa
        exclude = ['series', 'number', 'name', 'citizenship]
        fields = '__all__'
        fieldsets = [
            ('main',
             {'fields': ('name', 'citizenship'),
              'legend': 'I. PERSONAL DATA'}
             ),
            ('main1',
             {'fields': ('series', 'number'),
              'legend': 'II. PROFESSIONAL IDENTIFICATION'}
             )]
```